How to lift some object in Gazebo Harmonics?
I am making my "Hello, World" plugin in Gazebo Harmonics. I'm trying to lift some object upwards, i. e. to move it with the constant speed. Like this I plan to understand C++ classes to be used in plugins. In future like this I will implement my own quadcopter model with my control etc.
I have found a plugin example in tutorials that follows.
As far as I understand, I have to make my changes in the PostUpdate call. I. e. I have to change position of my object, or I can speficy some force and its direction. But not clear how to do it. Could you suggest me some idea?
I have found classes list
here. If there is more user friendly classes usage description or some kind of tutorial?
#include <gz/sim/EntityComponentManager.hh>
#include <gz/sim/System.hh>
#include <gz/sim/components/Link.hh>
#include <gz/sim/components/Name.hh>
#include <gz/sim/components/ParentEntity.hh>
#include <gz/sim/components/Pose.hh>
#include <gz/plugin/Register.hh>
 
using namespace gz;
using namespace sim;
using namespace systems;
 
class MyPlugin: public System, public ISystemConfigure, public ISystemPostUpdate
{
  virtual void Configure(const Entity &_entity, const std::shared_ptr<const sdf::Element> &_sdf, EntityComponentManager &_ecm, EventManager &/*_eventMgr*/) override
  {
    auto linkName = _sdf->Get<std::string>("brick"); // object name ?
 
    this->linkEntity = _ecm.EntityByComponents(
        components::ParentEntity(_entity),
        components::Name(linkName), components::Link());
  }
 
  virtual void PostUpdate(const UpdateInfo &_info, const EntityComponentManager &_ecm) override
  {
    auto pose = _ecm.Component<components::Pose>(this->linkEntity)->Data();

// to do something here?

    std::cout << pose << std::endl;
  }
 
  private: Entity linkEntity;
};
 
GZ_ADD_PLUGIN(MyPlugin, gz::sim::System, MyPlugin::ISystemConfigure, MyPlugin::ISystemPostUpdate)
 
GZ_ADD_PLUGIN_ALIAS(MyPlugin, "gz::sim::systems::MyPlugin")

sdf-file:
<sdf version="1.9">
    <model name="brick_drone">
        <pose>0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>
        <link name="brick">
            <inertial>
                <mass>1.0</mass>
                <inertia>
                    <ixx>0.001</ixx>
                    <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                    <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                    <iyy>0.001</iyy>
                    <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                    <izz>0.001</izz>
                </inertia>
            </inertial>
            <visual name="brick_visual">
                <geometry>
                    <box>
                        <size>0.2 0.1 0.1</size>
                    </box>
                </geometry>
                <material>
                    <ambient>1 0 0 1</ambient> <!-- Red color -->
                    <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse> <!-- Red color -->
                    <specular>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</specular> <!-- Slight shine -->
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision name="brick_collision">
                <geometry>
                    <box>
                        <size>0.2 0.1 0.1</size>
                    </box>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <plugin
            filename="build/libbrick_lift_plugin.so"
            name="gz::sim::systems::MyPlugin"/>
    </model>
</sdf>

